# Convert a Map<T, Value> to a List<T> based on parameter of the object and value

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, groupingby

I have a map `Map<MetricResult, Long> metricResultToComputationTime`.

`MetricResult` has a method `MetricResult::getEndTime`.

I want to get a `List<MetricResult>` where every `MetricResult` has a unique end time. If end times match, I want to use the one with the greater computation time from the map. How do I do this neatly?

I know there are simple wordy ways to do this, but I'm looking for something elegant.

I tried some stuff like this:

```java
List<MetricResult> metricResults =
    metricResultToComputationTime.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(
            groupingBy(
                MetricResult::getEndTime,
                collectingAndThen(maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()), Optional::get)))
        .values();
```

But it doesn't compile

Error:

> no suitable method found for
> collect(java.util.stream.Collector<MetricResult&java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Object,V>,capture#1
> of ?,java.util.Map<Timestamp,java.lang.Object>>) method
> java.util.stream.Stream.collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,?
> super
> java.util.Map.Entry<MetricResult,Timestamp>>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>)
> is not applicable (inference variable T has incompatible bounds upper
> bounds: MetricResult,java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>,T,T lower bounds:
> MetricResult,Timestamp>)

Comment: and what error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minor modifications:

1. Change `MetricResult::getEndTime` to obtain *endTime* from entry: `ent -> ent.getKey().getEndTime()`.
2. Map grouped entry results to a list with `values().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList()`.

```java
List<MetricResult> metricResults =
    metricResultToComputationTime.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
            ent -> ent.getKey().getEndTime(),
            collectingAndThen(maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()), Optional::get)))
        .values().stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList();
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I think it should be collect(toList()), but otherwise this was perfect.

I had a test ready to go, and I can confirm this worked as expected.

Comment: I actually spotted the ent.getKey().getEndTime() requirement. What I missed was that it generates a map<map<>>, so you need to get values and then the keyset! Thanks so much, that would have taken me a while!

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion. Thus, a resulting `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList()` should be replaced with `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(toList())`?

Comment: @AkhilCherianVerghese "I think it should be collect(toList()), but otherwise this was perfect." — `stream.toList` was added in Java 16.  `collect(toList())` works in all versions of Java.  The biggest difference is that `Stream.toList` returns an immutable `List`, but `collect(toList())` doesn't have mutability guarantees (but current implementations return a mutable implementation in practice).